# how to define an array in template (not use .ts)

Tags: angular

I know the best way is to define a variable from the .ts. But in this case I require to be able to do an `*ngFor` from a given number, where this number will be an array with this number of positions.

My idea is something like this:

```
<ng-container * ngFor = "let item of new Array(number)>
  ...
</ng-container>
```

for example: number =3

```
<ng-container * ngFor = "let item of new Array(3)>
  repetat 3 times
</ng-container>
```

is it possible?

Comment: Possible, yes, bad idea, likely yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, using a string. An initial string `'x'` is repeated the desired number of times. The array is then obtained by splitting the string on each character.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of 'x'.repeat(count).split('')">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjyrlp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.