# Equivalent of simple "for" (iterating with index) of C# in Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

In a razor page I can write:

```
 @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.TotPages; i++)
    {
        <div class="pagmenu">
            @if (i == Model.CurPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Index", "Home", new { curPage = i, catId = Model.CatId, discounted = Model.Discounted, search= Model.Search }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Index", "Home", new { curPage = i, catId = Model.CatId, discounted = Model.Discounted, search = Model.Search }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            }
        </div>
    }
```

What is the equivalent in angular?
`*ngFor` is the equivalent of `foreach` not of `for`, as I understand it.

Comment: There is only foreach in Angular. You can get index like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Angular you only can iterating over arrays, well you can create an array "on fly" using "repeat", see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980593/how-to-define-an-array-in-template-not-use-ts/60980775#60980775)

```
//in ts
n=10;

<div *ngFor="let a of ' '.repeat(n).split('');let i=index">
  {{i}}
</div>
```

or using a function to return an array

```
//in .ts
n=10;
getFoolArray(n)
{
    return new Array(n)
}

<div *ngFor="let a of getFoolArray(n);let i=index">
  {{i}}
</div>
```

Another option is create a directive repeat, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850607/how-to-replicate-normal-for-loop-to-ngfor/53850863#53850863)

Comment: For reference, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980775/1009922).

Comment: @ConnorsFan, really, I didn't saw your post, please, don't think it's stolen (else I usually redirect to the link)